# Is there a way to use the on_touch_move value in the main(App) class in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Is there a way to use the on_touch_move value of a widget in the main(App) class in kivy? I want to use the value of touch.spos in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to `kivy.core.window.Window.on_touch_move`, or other similar events, as described in [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html).

Alternatively you could have the `on_touch_move` method of one of your widgets call a function of the app class, which is effectively the same result.